# Retrieving a random sample of data from TestCaseSource in NUnit 3.0 attribute doesn't work?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

I'm having a strange issue utilizing this combination of technologies:

- Nunit(3.4.1.0)
- NUnit 3 Visual Studio Test Adapter
- TestCaseSource attribute

My test uses the attribute like this:

```
        [Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(GetSmallSampleSizeOfTestDataForScratchwork))]
    public void TestMe(string accessionNumber, string loginId)
    {
        var studentAssessmentPage = OpenAdminResetPageAndGoToBookletLocation(accessionNumber, loginId);
        studentAssessmentPage.OpenScratchworkTool();
        Assert.IsTrue(studentAssessmentPage.IsScratchworkToolOpen(), "The scratchwork tool did not open succesfully.");
    }
```

The implementation of GetSmallSampleSizeOfTestDataForScratchwork() doesn't run any tests whenever I try to execute the test. Even though in debug mode it works as expected.

```
protected static IEnumerable<string[]> GetSmallSampleSizeOfTestDataForScratchwork()
    {
        var filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        filePath = Path.GetFullPath(filePath + @"\TestData\TestData.csv");

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            var reader = new CsvReader(sr);
            IEnumerable<CsvRecord> records = reader.GetRecords<CsvRecord>().OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid());

            foreach (var record in records.Take(10))
            {
                string column1 = record.AccessionNumber;
                string column2 = record.LoginId;
                yield return new[] { column1, column2 };
            }
        }
    }
```

However, this implementation works just fine and runs all of the tests without a problem.

```
        protected static IEnumerable<string[]> GetAllTestDataForScratchwork()
    {
        var filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        filePath = Path.GetFullPath(filePath + @"\TestData\TestData.csv");

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            var reader = new CsvReader(sr);
            IEnumerable<CsvRecord> records = reader.GetRecords<CsvRecord>();

            foreach (var record in records)
            {
                string column1 = record.AccessionNumber;
                string column2 = record.LoginId;
                yield return new[] { column1, column2 };
            }
        }
    }
```

The only difference between these 2 methods are that 1 returns a random subset of data and the other returns all of the data.

**Therefore, why is it that GetAllTestDataForScratchwork() works just fine when I execute the tests and GetSmallSampleSizeOfTestDataForScratchwork() doesn't run a single test?**

Comment: You have not said how you run tests: NUnit3-console? NUnit 3 VS adapter? NUnit Gui? R#? etc.

Comment: Oops, thanks @charlie I am running using NUnit 3 VS adapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: This is a limitation of running under the VS adapter. You cannot use any random values or random selection of data unless the random numbers are provided by NUnit itself through TestContext.

(Much) longer answer: https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/240